# image overlaps text view in android activity

Tags: android, textview

Hi i am new to android and i have the following problem(see image).

[image]

As seen above the image over laps the text view. Can any one help me correct it.

I am using the following code.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/outlet_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="170dp"            
            android:hint="@string/outlet_id_text"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/search_button"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="-48dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cd_search_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/search_icon" />





<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout       
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <org.fluturasymphony.recommendation.ScrollingTextView

        android:text="Really Long Scrolling Text Goes Here.... ..... ............ .... ...."

        android:singleLine="true"

        android:ellipsize="marquee"

        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"

        android:scrollHorizontally="true"

        android:id="@+id/TextView03"

        android:padding="25dip" 

        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 

        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/outlet_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="170dp"            
            android:hint="@string/outlet_id_text"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/search_button"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="-48dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cd_search_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/search_icon" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/view_stores_on_map"
            android:layout_width="221dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
            android:onClick="showStoreList"
            android:text="@string/view_stores_on_map" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/view_stores"

        android:layout_width="221dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:onClick="showStoreList"
        android:text="View List Of Stores" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what layout are you using? you should use `RelativeLayout` and define the `layoutAbove`

Comment: @user1844638 where you want to display image,

Comment: i am using a relative layout

Comment: @user1844638 please post full xml code here.

Comment: @user1844638 if you want to put imageview beside textview use linear layout.

Comment: i posted my xml code above

Comment: hi .. you have the options like  android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher" in edit text itself.. you can use that right.

Comment: but wont that put the image to the extreme right. what i want is to put the image beside the text view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <org.fluturasymphony.recommendation.ScrollingTextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:padding="25dip"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Really Long Scrolling Text Goes Here.... ..... ............ .... ...." />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
            android:background="@color/background"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/outlet_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/outlet_id_text"
                android:inputType="textAutoComplete" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/search_button"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/cd_search_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/search_icon" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/view_stores_on_map"
            android:layout_width="221dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
            android:onClick="showStoreList"
            android:text="@string/view_stores_on_map" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/view_stores"
            android:layout_width="221dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:onClick="showStoreList"
            android:text="View List Of Stores" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It will solve your problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi do you know how to implement this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119334/text-view-is-not-scrolling

Comment: @user1844638 I just see your message , is your problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following lines also . or if you want to use as a row items you can use orientation for those two items alone.

```
  <EditText
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/outlet_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="170dp"            
            android:hint="outlet_id_text"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete" />
```

Answer (score 2):

***Although you can manage your design using relative layout (BUT keep in mind your use is only show search image, so no need to add extra view for this requirement.), Here is simplest way is to do this***

Use the [`android:drawableTop`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableTop) property on the EditText.

```
<EditText
    ...     
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_action_search" />
```

and remove the `<ImageView>`

Other options are : 
`android:drawableRight`, `android:drawableLeft`,  `android:drawableBottom` and more..

Comment: how do you reduce the width and height of the image. its really big if i do that.

Comment: You can set height of edittext to reduce height of image and you can add padding between drawable and text in text view using `android:drawablePadding="3dp"`. But I will suggest you to use smaller image. Follow the UI design patterns and make smaller image.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna make it move up, change `android:layout_marginTop` of image view to a more negative value. Do the opposite if you need it to go down.

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/search_button"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="-48dp" <!-- add more  -ve value to move up, decrease to move down -->
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/cd_search_icon"
    android:src="@drawable/search_icon" />
```

Comment: i dont want to move it up i need to move it to the right so that the image is right next to the text view.

Answer (score 1):

Try this I hope it will work.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="40dp">
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/outlet_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/outlet_id_text"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/search_button"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cd_search_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use android:layout_below="@+id/search_button"   attribute to arrange your gadgets in View.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/outlet_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/search_button"           
        android:hint="@string/outlet_id_text"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cd_search_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/search_icon" />
```